# Getting a WCF service to map POST'd parameters to arguments

Tags: wcf, asmx

I have a legacy service I'm looking to update to WCF and one of it's behaviours is to allow clients to POST a request that has something like:

MyService.asmx/ProcessDocument
With Post data looking like:

```
request=<big block of xml>
```

Now in the ASMX days this service accepted a single string parameter i.e:

```
public void ProcessDocument(string request) {
}
```

So far I have only gotten this to work in WCF by using a Stream as of the advice in this post here:
http://www.dennydotnet.com/post/2008/09/16/WCF-REST-and-POST-Lets-Dance!.aspx

A Stream will work, there are just more steps involved to make it work for something that seems to it should be supported out of the box.

I am pretty new to WCF - what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this sample got me to most of where I needed to go:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943485.aspx

I now have it working as required.